# gremlin javascript can't collect the properties of a vertex

Tags: graph-theory, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, amazon-neptune

After inserting a vertex in amazon neptune , I get the an unique id . If I want to print out the properties of a vertex , I can do it easily in gremlin console

[image]

But in my node js app , if I try to do the same I can't get the properties of the vertex

Here is what  I have done in javascript

```
const fetchPropertyByVertexId = async (vertexId) => {
  console.log("requsting properties of vertex "+vertexId);
  return await g.V(vertexId).properties();
}
```

and then , I call

```
   fetchPropertyByVertexId(vertexId).then( property =>{
     console.log(property);
   });
```

And the output is

[image]

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gremlin)  library to connect with amazon neptune . 
How can I get property of a vertex , in key value pair , like I get it in gremlin console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to [iterate your traversal](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration). This:

```
return await g.V(vertexId).properties();
```

returns a `Traversal` object which does not return results - it just represents the object to iterate to get results. So, you need to include a terminal step like `toList()`:

```
return await g.V(vertexId).properties().toList();
```